# Application error:Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, configuration-files, config

I am working on the .net, when I am running my application I am getting this error. Can anyone help me?

```
Application Error -
MESSAGE: Could not load file or assembly 'ConfigurationMgr, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
SOURCE: BusinessLayer
TARGETSITE: Void .ctor()
STACKTRACE:
  at BusinessLayer.BL..ctor()
  at Marketing_BulkSMS..ctor()
  at ASP.marketing_bulksms_aspx..ctor()
  at __ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_q3yaaskd.Create_ASP_marketing_bulksms_aspx()
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCompiledType.CreateInstance()
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)
  at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
  at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you are missing a ConfigurationMgr.dll file in your bin folder, or the ConfigurationMgr.dll in your bin folder is a different version than the one specified in your Web.config.